# Android API 18 reacts to "interruptions" with onStop event

Tags: android, events, android-version

By "interruption" I mean something like receiving a call and answering it, putting the phone call over the application, receiving a popup whatsapp message on top of the application and so on, with the interruption always being caused by an external app.

I've tested my app in APIs from 19 to 25, except for 20 and in this APIs what fires with that interruption is either a onSaveInstance and onResume events or just a onResume event.

But in API 18 that "interruption" forces a onStop(). Problem is that in my app if some conditions are met on that onStop function the app must finish, and unlucky enough if the "interruption" comes in this version that conditions happen and the app finishes.

Would be there any way to force app to react with a OnSaveInstance, OnResume or just onResume like other versions? Or any way to tell the app that the onStop() is being caused by an external app?

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trying to figure out what "caused" the `onStop()`; the framework is just doing its job by keeping you abreast of the activity's [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle). (If you find that other API levels behave differently, it may be because they use transparent overlays or something during certain "interruptions," and therefor the activity is still technically on-screen).

The root cause is an application design issue. You may want to reevaluate when you choose to "process the user's input" (or whatever it is you're currently doing in `onStop()`). By choosing `onStop()`, you're telling the system, "I want you to run this whenever the activity goes offscreen," and with the wide variety of devices & API levels that are out there, that can happen at *many different times*.

Consider having the user press a button when it's time to "process the input." Or, you may want to move the processing to a different "layer" of the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ActivityLifecycle); to `onResume()/onPause()`, perhaps, or `onCreate()/onDestroy()`.